# Linux Centos 6.9 Gnome, in terminal Window, Commands Not found of program, ping command works ifconfig does not work

Tags: bash, shell, gnome, desktop

Linux Centos 6.9 Gnome,   in terminal  commands found of programs, ping command works ifconfig does not work

if i run remotely from ssh all commands work, using root.

Any idea? Thank you

I reloaded bash profile

[image]

Putty:

```
[root@XXXXXX ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  DATA REMOVED 

lo       DATA REMOVED 

[root@XXXXX ~]#
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The PATH variable must have different values in the Gnome window and the ssh session. In an ssh session, use `type ifconfig` to find its location, then adjust PATH accordingly.

Comment: Notably, /sbin is missing from your $PATH.

Comment: sbin is  in my path even rebooted :(